# What filesystem mount point am I currently working on?

Tags: filesystems, directory, directory-structure, command

I would like to know in what filesystem mount point I am currently on, similarly to using `pwd` to know what directory I am in.

I know you can use `df .` (or `df $(pwd)` or many variants), but I find it somehow overkilling to check the file system usage just to know where I am.

So: is there any command showing in what filesystem mount point I am?

Comment: `alias fs="df . | awk 'NR==2{print \$1}'"` :^)

Comment: @confused00 thanks, but I am not looking for an alias or any workaround: the question is about the existence of a command (builtin maybe) to give this info straight ahead.

Comment: By “what filesystem”, do you mean the filesystem type (e.g. ext4, zfs, …), or the mount point (e.g. `/`, `/home`, …), or something else?

Comment: @Gilles the mount point. Just updated to give more clarity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think `df .` is your best bet. The filesystem usage check is not that expensive (it doesn't have to count any blocks on disk, that information is readily available and stored in memory once the filesystem is mounted).

Alternatives like comparing the current path against mount points by using a script would be more expensive.

Comment: Interesting... so `df` does not perform any further calculation? Maybe it is off topic in this question but then, how often and by what procedure is the `df` info updated?

Comment: @fedorqui The filesystem "driver" keeps track of what blocks it allocates and frees for normal write operations. That information is stored on the disc as well (read in during mount, and can often be recalculated during a filesystem check), but normally a `df` doesn't have to go to disk to give you the number of Gb free on your disk or other data it displays.

Comment: @fedorqui You may be interested in trying `stat -f .`. It produces some of the same information as `df .` but is a more "raw" presentation. Both `stat -f` and `df` obtain this information through a single system call, `statvfs()`, and this system call gives you the usage statistics along with the file system's identification. So even at the system call level, this information comes all together. The usage statistics are expected to be cheap to retrieve.

Comment: So 1) there is not a "direct" command for this 2) is not that expensive to run. That's what I wanted to know, many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by "what filesystem".

If it means what instance of a filesystem, then using `df $(pwd)` may be your best bet, except when you know that the file you are inspecting actually is a mountpoint on its own, than using `mountpoint $(pwd)` may be a better idea.

If it means what type of filesystem, then use the common Linux utility `stat`, it only inspects the files you are giving as arguments and it also supports printing filesystem informations given any type of file, just type

```
stat -f $(pwd)
```

If you need to retrieve the type of filesystem to a given file programmatically, try one of these:

```
LC_ALL=C stat -f $(pwd) | awk '/\<Type: /{print $6}'
```

`sed` or plain shell pattern expansion can also be used to parse the `Type` field from the output of stat.

Comment: Good one, also `stat -f .` makes it. Only that it prints the filesystem type, not its name.

Comment: Title is "Is it possible to know what filesystem am I currently working on?", I don't think it is that ambiguous :)